# AMD Radeon 530 Driver

Tags: 18.04, radeon, amd-graphics

Does anyone here know how to install amd radeon 530 in my ubuntu 18.04?
I try to install my amd driver using amdgpu-pro-install command but it did't work.

Comment: I understand that drivers on AMD graphics are now installed by default. Please verify.

Comment: Hi Mark and welcome to askubuntu!  In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, you should add the commands and error messages given in the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

The open source `radeon` driver is now installed by default. The `amdgpu-pro` driver is installed only for supported cards, that you can [find here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx) and the 530 isn't a card that is supported by that driver

You can confirm this by using:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
```